# DataTables warning: table id=example - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information

Tags: jquery, angular, datatables, angular2-forms

I am using angular 4 with data table ... Right side scroll bar is not working. When I add this the in my data table I am getting this error. how can I solve this? 
this is my code 

`$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "scrollX": true
    } );
} );`

`<table id="example" class="display nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">`

I am getting a message in an alert on my browser "**DataTables warning: table id=example - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information**"

I am using this data table [enter link description here](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/extensions/select)

Comment: you are using `angularjs` then why you initialize `scrollx` using a `jquery` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dtOptions = {
      scrollX: true
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue arises if there is a previous initialization of DataTable. So, either set the `bDestroy` property of the DataTable to true like the following,

```
$('#dataTable').dataTable({
    .
    .        
    "bDestroy": true
});
```

OR remove the previously initialised DataTable such as initializing in the begining of the `onload`/`ready` method like the following,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.dataTable').dataTable();
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
this.dtOptions = {
      ...
      destroy: true,
      ...
    };
```